# Where clause variable in query being ignored

Tags: php, mysql, variables, where-clause

Newbie here.  When I put a date ('YYYY-MM-DD') in the WHERE clause, it works great.  When I replace it with a variable that is passed from the previous page, the WHERE clause is ignored.  Is it because the variable hasn't been created yet?

```
<?php $name = $_POST["start"]; ?>

$query = "SELECT employees.first, employees.last, employees.street, employees.city,  
employees.a, employees.b,  
GROUP_CONCAT(empchecks.checknum ORDER BY empchecks.checkdate SEPARATOR '<br /> ') as  
checknum, 
GROUP_CONCAT(empchecks.checkdate ORDER BY empchecks.checkdate      
SEPARATOR '<br /> ')  
as checkdate 
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN empchecks ON employees.enum = empchecks.enum 
WHERE empchecks.checkdate >= '$start' GROUP BY empchecks.enum";
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Can you verify the value of $start? That is, if you echo $query, what's it say? And what Daniel says, too. :) And it's not likely being ignored; rather, the checkdate comparison is likely evaluating to true ($start being a null string or anything that is coerced into being the start of epoch, etc.).

Comment: Given your code, `$start` hasn't been defined. More importantly, depending on how you sanitize your input variables, your technique of variable interpolation may leave you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It's empty.  But if I echo out $start outside of the query, it tells me the date I entered on previous page.

Answer (score 3):

The variable $start does not exist. Try replacing it with $name and see if it works. You should also use sprintf http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php to pass in variables for the query instead.

Comment: Same results with $name in sql.  When I echo $query, $start/$name is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're assigning `$_POST['start']` to `$name` and not to `$start` which you're refering to later.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST is "start", but you assign it to "name"

So use $name in your SQL...

Comment: 13mins ago? while all of you have 10, 11 or 12 mins? I was the first one ;)

Answer (score 0):

write this
    extract($_POST)
To be able to use $start instead of $name